# Get content of tags with empty id in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = """<span id="something">useless</span>
          <span id="">some text</span>
          <span id="different">useless</span>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
```

How can I get `some text` only? Using `soup.find_all('span', {'id': ""})` finds everything.

Comment: What is your bs4 version? `soup.find_all('span', {'id': ""})` is work on `4.3.2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. use a custom filter; pass in a function and it'll be asked to return `True` or `False` for elements:

   ```
   soup.find_all(lambda e: e.name == 'span' and e.attrs.get('id') == '')
   ```
2. Use a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors), with an exact attribute match:

   ```
   soup.select('span[id=""]')
   ```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> page = """<span id="something">useless</span>
...           <span id="">some text</span>
...           <span id="different">useless</span>"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
>>> soup.find_all(lambda e: e.name == 'span' and e.attrs.get('id') == '')
[<span id="">some text</span>]
>>> soup.select('span[id=""]')
[<span id="">some text</span>]
```

Comment: Is there a way to not return a list? Such that I can apply more BeautifulSoup related operations (.e.g. `.text` of additional `.find()`)?

Comment: @MERose: you can loop over the list. If you are looking for just *one* element, use `soup.find()`; it takes the exact same arguments as `find_all()` but returns only the first hit or `None`.

Comment: @MERose: but if you want to process all such elements looping over `.find_all()` is your best option.